# Not able to uninstall Db2 express C from windows 7

Tags: db2, uninstallation

I removed all the folders manually from

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB
C:\ProgramData\IBM\DB2\DB2COPY1
C:\DB2\NODE0000
```

Then I tried uninstalled from control panel but am unable to remove Db2 .Popup appears with message as 'please wait window configures...' and after that nothing happens. Software still remains in system

Comment: So, you tried to remove a software in Windows using not supported way. Did I get it right, that now you ask about how to remove properly all the huge number of corresponding to Db2 entries from Windows registry manually?

Comment: I removed directly from Control panel .Don't know that is suported way or not .But this was install from project package with defend point access .Please help if you know how to uninstall

Comment: You said, that you removed Db2 directories **first** and tried to remove Db2 using control panel **afterwards**. Is this correct?

Comment: No first I tried before removal of folder structure.. The later I removed based upon project doc.. I may be wrong here. Please let me know what to do here for removal from control panel

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [Uninstalling and removing DB2 for Windows](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/uninstalling-and-removing-db2-windows) article.